# Handling server being aware if iPhone app is running (heartbeat)

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, apple-push-notifications

I am not sure how to best implement keeping our server informed that our iPhone application is currently running (even when in the background). There are a few different options but there is some concern as to what is allowed by the Apple approval process as well as what is the most reliable. The application does have the ability to play music in the background, if that factors into what is approved by Apple.

The first option, is to continually send some sort of heartbeat to the server at a set interval through a simple GET/POST; however, the concern is whether or not this is allowed as a background task. In a very roundabout way it can be argued that it is necessary for the playback but I'm not so sure whether or not that is acceptable. If the server does not hear from them in a set amount of time it will assume the app is no longer running.

The second option involves using a presence channel socket connection and have the server just handle when users enter and leave that channel. With this option the main concern is how reliable is a socket connection like this while an app is in the background. Similarly, whether or not this is allowed by Apple. In this case when the app dies, connection closes and server knows app is not running.

Third option can be used in tandem with either of the other options but to use some sort of APNS push to query the phone as to whether or not it has died and have it respond with some data to let us know; however, this seems somewhat counterintuitive as the push itself wakes the app up.

Any other suggestions or input are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this should be a comment or answer, but let me put my 2 cents here.

Firstly, Can you please elaborate your needs further, because in case you are playing an Audio in background with `AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem` you would hand over your content URL to iOS and it will make the calls as and when necessary to keep the playback running, you dont need to know about apps' state.

Let me assume, for whatever reasons you want to achieve what the question asks:

1. There are 3 states your app can be in when it is "**Not Running**"

   i. **Suspended State**: your app is not killed but its not receiving any CPU time to execute your code.

   ii. **Killed by OS**: Your app can be terminated by iOS to free up the memory or any other resources.

   iii. **Force Killed by User**: If user swipes up your app from app switcher it gets force killed.

   Now when your app is **Not Running**, you **CAN NOT query it**, but you can move it to **Running** State. You can achieve this transition by using following methods (Not exhaustive list, but mentions common ways)

   i. **Background Fetch** : You can configure your app to be invoked periodically, so that it can synchronise with the server and updates its state.

   ii. **Push Notifications (APNS)** : You can ping the app from server so that iOS invokes it for some short period of time (few seconds) to update its state.

   iii. **VOIP Pushes**: If your App is VOIP app you can use PushKit to send Silent Pushes which will launch even the Force-Killed Apps, the above two methods does not transition the app to Running state if it was force killed by user
2. The above point can be helpful in devising overall strategy but does not answer the question, **"How to keep syncing the RUNNING state"**

   i. When your app is Running(Forground/Background), you can do almost anything that is publicly documented, you can keep calling a URL every minute or every 5 seconds, you need to worry about UX on the device rather than approval process, (People will delete app if they see your app in top battery drainers in the settings section)

   ii. For making an HTTP call while your app is in background, you can look at [Background URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44), which off loads the HTTP calls to another process so that the call completes even if app gets killed.

   iii. For the socket based approach please refer [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2277/_index.html). The main issue is that you do not/can not know when your app moves from **Running** to **Not Running** State.

   iv. As you mentioned that your app uses background audio, it will be always be in Running state if the user plays an audio and puts app in background, in such case you can use [Periodic Observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:) to do some Heartbeat call periodically when the content is being played out.